# How to hide Payment information on my custom payment extension

Tags: magento

I made a new payment module in which the client fills he's bank account information.
I use the info block which displays info on the progress sidebar, admin and goes to the customer email.
I need the information showed on the first two but I don't want some of the fields showing on the email.
Can the info block be configured not to show some information only in case of email?

Thanks.

Comment: You have over 100 rep, you should know how to write a question in a format someone can actually answer by now. Please follow [these guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, 
1. payment methods have templates which are inserted in the email to the customer

1. the info class defined the template to be used
   protected function _construct()
   {
       parent::_construct();
       $this->setTemplate('payment/info/{new template}.phtml');
   }
   and that's how you control the payment details in the customer email

   - Dont Forget to create the template for the adminhtml as well

hope it's been helpful :)